# Multindexing in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working with jypyther-python. I created a data set the following way:

```
scr_spread=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/e877780/Desktop/DEV/scr_spread.txt',sep=";")
#scr_spread['idx']=range(1,len(scr_spread)+1)
scr_spread.set_index(['Tipo','Rating','Duration_hasta'], inplace=True)
scr_spread=scr_spread.sort_index()
```

The data set has one additional field, 'Duramaxima. I am trying to get just the 'Duramaxima' that corresponds to a triplet, for example (1,1,5). I use the following syntax:

```
scr_spread.loc[(1,1,5),'DuraMaxima']
```

If I define a=2*the value from above and printout, I get the following:
[image]

How do I just get the 346 and not the triplet plus result of the multiplication. I need the 346 for another dataset.
Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try `a.values`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using tuple for accessing some row in `.loc`, it returns pandas Series.
So by `print(a.iloc[0])` you obtain just 346.